# image comparison in asp .net (for rotated images)

Tags: asp.net, .net, c#-4.0, image-processing

In my code I want to compare two images

if one image is rotated, should show matching result

I use this code

```
ImageConverter imgConverter = new ImageConverter();

    byte[] img1Bytes = new byte[1];
    byte[] img2Bytes = new byte[1];

    img1Bytes = (byte[])imgConverter.ConvertTo(img1Bitmap, img1Bytes.GetType());
    img2Bytes = (byte[])imgConverter.ConvertTo(img2Bitmap, img2Bytes.GetType());

    SHA256Managed sha256Managed = new SHA256Managed();

    byte[] hash1 = sha256Managed.ComputeHash(img1Bytes);
    byte[] hash2 = sha256Managed.ComputeHash(img2Bytes);

    int i = 0;
    int flag = 1;

    for ( i = 0; i < hash1.Length && i < hash2.Length && flag==1; i++)
    {
        if (hash1[i] != hash2[i])
            flag =0;
    }
    if (flag ==1)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
```

but in this code it will compare only same image not applicable for rotated image